# Flutter Provider doesn't rebuild widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

here's a piece of my code, 
but please read the question before jumping to conclusions:

```
class RescheduleCard extends StatelessWidget {

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)=> Consumer<AppSnapshot>(
    builder: (context, appSnapshot, _)=>
    (appSnapshot.reschedule!=null)
    ?RescheduleBuilder(
          model: appSnapshot.reschedule,
          controllers: appSnapshot.controllers,
        )
    :Carouselcard(
      title:  carouselPageTitle(title: rescheduleTitle,test: appSnapshot.test),
      colors: yellows,
```

so I'm sort of new to provider and I'm used to Bloc,
my api once receive some call the provider and set a model;

edit: here's the provider 256 lines tripped down to what concern
the "reschedule"...

```
class AppSnapshot with ChangeNotifier {

  RescheduleModel _reschedule;
  RescheduleModel get reschedule => _reschedule;

  void cleanReschedule() {
    reschedule=null;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set reschedule(RescheduleModel reschedule) {
    _reschedule=reschedule;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

re-edit: on top of everything:

```
void main() async {
  final AppSnapshot _appSnapshot = AppSnapshot();
  await _appSnapshot.load();
  runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider(
          builder: (context) => _appSnapshot,
          child: Initializer()));
}
```

I'm expecting the "Consumer" to rebuild my widget,
but doesn't!

I'm sure the data is there, because the widget is inside a carousel
and as soon as I move it it rebuilds properly.

what am I missing?
thank you

re-re-edit:  here's an example of another Carousel Card where provider works quilckly and changes apply in realtime

```
 Consumer<AppSnapshot>(
    builder: (context, appSnapshot, _)=> Carouselcard(
      title: carouselPageTitle(title: optionsTitle,test: appSnapshot.test),
      colors: lightBlues,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          ((appSnapshot.id??'')!='')                                                        // ID WIDGET
            ? ListTile(
              leading: CustomIcon(
                icon: deleteIcon,
                onTap: () => appSnapshot.deleteID(),
              ),
              title: _customCard(onTap:()=> _showID(id: appSnapshot.id,context: context)),
              subtitle: Text(tap2delete,textScaleFactor:0.8),
            )
            : IdTile(),
```

Comment: Can you share us more? We need the provider

Comment: for the man himself, of course :) I stripped down the provider to what is related to the object otherwise it would be a lot of code... note that in other widgets the provider works as intended, even here it passes the data, just doesn't rebuilds until otherwise refreshed

Comment: I was more thinking about `ChangeNotifierProvider`. Similarly, are you *sure* that the `builder` method isn't called again? If you add a log there, it's not reached?

Comment: post updated... but hold on... I can "consume" more than once, can I?

Comment: You sure can. Is here another provider of an object of the type `AppSnapshot` ?

Comment: a lot of them.... there are many object in it and some business logic, I posted a working one, I don't see much difference to be hones :/

Comment: I don't mean other consumers, but other providers. Do you have only one provider for this kind of object?

Comment: oh sorry, no, only the one "on top"

Comment: And have you tried adding a `print` inside the Consumer?

Comment: crap, I need to go. I'll do that tomorrow, I'll make some logging and see if I can find some clue... thanks for the help @RémiRousselet

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/making-sense-all-of-those-flutter-providers-e842e18f45dd) the `FutureProvider` does not listen for changes, it will only rebuild `Consumers` 1 time, when Future is complete.

The article even explains how the author tested this.

The developer of the Dart Provider package also [explains the use case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57349706/use-case-for-futureprovider) for `FutureProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

Specificies the type in main.dart

```
void main() async {
final AppSnapshot _appSnapshot = AppSnapshot();
await _appSnapshot.load();
runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider< **AppSnapshot** >(
      builder: (context) => _appSnapshot,
      child: Initializer()));
}
```

Comment: Why do you think this would have any effect?