# Use case for FutureProvider

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, flutter-provider

I was wondering what use case exists for the `FutureProvider` class?

I am particularly interested how to load an asynchronous function like `Future<Contact> getAllContacts() async { ... }` when the ui is built with a `FutureProvider`, `ChangeNotifierProvider` or anything similar.

Moreover, each time when `notifyListeners()` is called, I would like to have that provider to rebuild the ui with asynchronous call. Is that any way possible with provider or am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`FutureProvider` doesn't come with a built-in update mechanism – but can be combined with `Consumer` and a mutable object (`ChangeNotifer` or `State`) to handle updates.

It has two main usages:

- Exposing an "immutable value" that needs to be asynchronously loaded (a config file for example):

```dart
FutureProvider<MyConfig>(
  builder: (_) async {
    final json = await // TODO load json from something;
    return MyConfig.fromJson(json); 
  }
)
```

- Alternatively, it can be combined with something that can mutate (like `ChangeNotifier`) to convert a `Future` into something easier to manipulate:

```dart
ChangeNotifierProvider(
  builder: (_) => Foo(),
  child: Consumer<Foo>(
    builder: (_, foo, __) {
      return FutureProvider.value(
        value: foo.someFuture,
        child: ...,
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to create a [gist](https://gist.github.com/hayribakici/b7aa6486aec9aa947ce9432c3de13c13) based on your answer that allows to display a child while the future operation is in progress.

Comment: Is there a way to set the provider when the Future returns?

Comment: Is there a clean way of using this pattern within `MultiProvider` ?

Comment: I appreciate your development of the Provider package but the sound logic eludes me for why there is a FutureProvider but not the likes of a "FutureChangeNotifierProvider". The latter seems like it would be the more common use case for state management, albeit harder to implement than the former.

Comment: @brianodgen because as soon as non nullable types are released, this would stop working

Comment: @RémiRousselet Would you provide us with a way to register change notifier proxy providers that depend on asynchronous work?  I sent you an email and posted a question on this topic but haven't heard back.