# How can i update and get again FutureProvider data?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

i want to know how to get updated data when i used FutureProvider.

How can i get and show updated data again when i click the button?

Does it have good way? or should i give up to use FutureProvider?

```
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: FutureProvider(
              create: (_) async => TestDao().findAll(),
              child: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page')),
        );
      }
    }

    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

      final String title;

      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }

    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        var testData = Provider.of<List<String>>(context);
        return Scaffold(
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                TestDao().insert('test');
              });
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
          body: Text('$testData'),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Actually FutureProvider doesn't have a built-in update but there is other solutions to achieve that. Check this answer for details. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57350028/12880676

Comment: What is the  problem you are facing with a provider, you can solve your problem with the provider only