# how to call api again using future provider?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am using future provider for getting api resonse but i want to call it again on value changed from dropdown how to do that ?

```
FutureProvider<Users>(
            initialData: UserModel(),
          
            create: (_)async=>Apis().getUsers(context, userurl));,
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use case for FutureProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57349706/use-case-for-futureprovider)

Comment: just use setstate to refresh

Comment: using stateless widget